# PostgreSQL order in recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, recursive-query

I try to get result of my query in natural order, but have a fail.

```
create table Tab2 (id int, F1 varchar(100));
insert into Tab2 values(1, '10,56,657,34,767,71');
insert into Tab2 values(3, '1,5487,27,9');
insert into Tab2 values(4, '11,13,37,2');
insert into Tab2 values(2, '12,6,65,8,67,22,70,5');


WITH RECURSIVE etc (id,  DataItem, F1)  AS (
                (SELECT id,
                LEFT(F1, strpos(concat(F1, ','), ',')-1) AS Part,
                overlay(F1 placing '' from 1 for strpos(concat(F1, ','),',')) AS Remainder
                FROM Tab2
                --ORDER BY Remainder
                )
    
 UNION ALL

                (SELECT id,
                LEFT(F1, strpos(concat(F1, ','), ',')-1),
                overlay(F1 placing '' from 1 for strpos(concat(F1, ','),','))
                FROM etc e
                WHERE F1 > ''
                --ORDER BY Dataitem
                 )
    )

SELECT id, row_number() over(partition BY id ORDER BY id) num, DataItem from etc ORDER BY id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0ccc6/89/0

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What do YOU mean by "natural order"?

Comment: Storing comma separated values in a single column is a big mistake to begin with. But you need to tell us which order you actually want

Comment: What issue are you facing? What is your expected recult?

Comment: Do you mean this: [SqlFiddle (after changes)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0ccc6/96)

Comment: @MaciejLos Yes! Its great! My respect for you! I thought about one additional column, but try to solve a problem with ORDER BY!  I am deeply grateful to you!!!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks you, natural in this case means for me sequense order in string. Of course it is a bad practice to store such things, but it was initial condition to make this task more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your query correctly you are trying to get all elements from your (badly designed) comma separated string. There is no need to use a recursive query for that.

You can convert the string to array which can then be "unnested" into rows. Using the option `with ordinality` will also return the index of each element in the array which can be used in an `order by` to preserve the original order of the items in the string.

```
select t2.id, i.num, i.dataitem
from tab2 t2
  cross join unnest(string_to_array(f1,',')) with ordinality as i(dataitem, num)
order by t2.id, i.num;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ade4394f18445b7e55c684b34a773e00)

Comment: Excellent! I've never used `unnest` function before. This is very interesting example of using it. Thanks for sharing it!

Comment: Thanks for your attention for my question. I understand this decision. And You are right with "badly designed" db, but it was a test task in CTE. And it was a new subject for me, but i solved it without recursion as SELECT id, row_number() over(partition BY id ORDER BY id) num, regexp_split_to_table(F1, ',') FROM Tab2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to get `DataItem` in order, in which it is placed in comma separated string, you can use another field to get an "index" (in below example it's a `rowno`).

For example:

```
id, dataitem
1, 10
1, 56
1, 657
...
1, 71
2, 12
...
2, 5
etc.
```

See:

```
WITH RECURSIVE etc (id, rowno,  DataItem, F1)  AS (
                (SELECT id, 1 as rowno,
                LEFT(F1, strpos(concat(F1, ','), ',')-1) AS Part,
                overlay(F1 placing '' from 1 for strpos(concat(F1, ','),',')) AS Remainder
                FROM Tab2
                )
    
 UNION ALL

                (SELECT id, rowno +1 as rowno,
                LEFT(F1, strpos(concat(F1, ','), ',')-1),
                overlay(F1 placing '' from 1 for strpos(concat(F1, ','),','))
                FROM etc e
                WHERE F1 > ''
                 )
    )

SELECT id, DataItem
from etc
ORDER BY id, RowNo;
```

[SqlFiddle (after changes)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0ccc6/96)

Comment: Yes! Its great! My respect for you! I thought about one additional column, but try to solve a problem with ORDER BY!  I am deeply grateful to you!!!

Comment: i solved it without recursion earlier  <pre>SELECT id, row_number() over(partition BY id ORDER BY id) num, regexp_split_to_table(F1, ',') FROM Tab2 <code>